# Writing a callback function in Python to be consumed by a C routine in a loaded API. Callback function has va_list

Tags: python, c, callback

There seems to be some ideas in writing Python callback functions to be consumed by  a load C api:  [Writing Python ctypes for Function pointer callback function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980167/writing-python-ctypes-for-function-pointer-callback-function-in-c)

Thanks!  This is useful.

I have some callback functions that are of the form:

LogCallback(enum messtype, OurNode *node, OurLink *link, OurContract *contract, char *format, va_list argptr)

I am mainly interested in how a python routine can be made to have a va_list such that it can be sent to an API call as a callback function.

Clarification:  The callback function format calls for a va_list, so a Python function built to act as a callback function would need to function in the C routines that take in and run this function (pointer).

Comment: I would expect you need to find a way to bind `LogCallback_wrapper(enum messtype, OurNode *, OurLink *, OurContract *, char *, ...)`, which can then construct the `va_list` correctly and invoke `LogCallback`.

Comment: I think paddy's got it, I don't think you'll find any sensible way of constructing `va_list` in ctypes.

Comment: or do you mean that you need to code a *Python* function that takes in `va_list` *and* processes it? That's 99 % impossibility... or at least 100 % masochism :D

Comment: Actually re-reading the question... it is unclear what do you need, perhaps *some* code would clarify.

Comment: Nothing would stop you from writing a C function to convert `format` and `argptr` into, say, a `tuple` which could be passed to whatever Python function.  Doing it entirely via `ctypes` is likely to be painful.

Comment: paddy, could you clarify what you are stating?  To further clarify, I want to code a Python function that can act as a callback function to be consumed by a C routine.  The said callback function has a va_list in its expected argument format.