# Calling the C++ function in python using ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have C++ code which has a function which takes, three arguments

1. Pointer argument
2. LPWSTR argument
3. (LPWSTR variable)reference as argument
   Below is the C++ Code syntax

```
HRESULT WINAPIV GIDItem (Address* pa, LPWSTR cmdvalue, LPWSTR* string_value)
```

I am able to load the dll in Ctypes

```
    import ctypes
    uDl = ctypes.CDLL(r"test1")
    uDl_function=uDl.CAIA  # we are creating function pointer
    pa=uDl_function('something')
    uD = ctypes.CDLL(r"test.dll")
    uD_function =uD.GIDItem # we are creating function pointer
    string_value= ctypes.c_wchar_p()
    cmdvalue=ctypes.c_wchar_p("CM")
    dI=uD_function(ctypes.POINTER(pa),cmdvalue,ctypes.byref(string_value))
```

I am getting below error,

```
dI=uD_function(ctypes.POINTER(pa),cmdvalue,ctypes.byref(string_value))
TypeError: must be a ctypes type
```

I was just looking some article about that DLL, in C++ the Dll been called like below

```
fpGIDItem (pA, L"CMD", &cD)
```

When you look to the above code "CMD" is the `cmdvalue` and string value is sent with `&cD`

Please help me over this

Comment: I can't tell where `pa` is declared. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just updated the code for `pa`.Thanks for looking to this

Comment: You probably need to include a minimal working example. In the meantime see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980167/writing-python-ctypes-for-function-pointer-callback-function-in-c) helps.

Comment: I don't have c++ dll code, i just know the input type, function name, and return

Comment: `TypeError: one character unicode string expected` any idea why is this error if i do `cmdvalue=ctypes.c_wchar("CM")`

Comment: Added C++ code function detail

Comment: I'm not sure I can help. But I think `uDl.CAIA` is the function pointer. So you wouldn't do `ctypes.POINTER(pa)` but instead just `uDl.CAIA`. I've never passed a function pointer from python to C, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212392/discussion-between-ashtav-and-gnodab).

Comment: `POINTER` is a type and you need an instance of a type.  Since the first parameter is `Address*` is can probably be just `pa` if that is what is returned from the first function.  `byref(string_value)` is actually passing a `wchar_t**` which isn't what you want either.  Just pass `string_value`.  Update your question with the full C prototypes of both functions if you want a better answer.

Comment: @MarkTolonen  I have added the code of how this API function uD_function is been called. This all information I got ! Sorry if it is still incomplete

Comment: What’s the C prototype of CAIA?

Comment: @MarkTolonen Here we go! --> `Address* (*CAIA)(LPCWSTR)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctypes.POINTER(pa)` is a **type** instead of an instance which is why it is giving the error you see.

If you create a working example of the use in C, it would be easier to identify how to write it in Python, but I'll take a stab at it.

Set `.argtypes` and `restype` on the function correctly so `ctypes` will type check for you.

Something like the following should work.

```
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL(r'test1')
dll.CAIA.argtypes = c_wchar_p,
dll.CAIA.restype = c_void_p     # generic void* should work.

dll2 = ctypes.CDLL(r'test.dll')
dll2.GIDItem.argtypes = c_void_p,c_wchar_p,POINTER(c_wchar_p)
dll2.GIDItem.restype = c_long

pa = dll.CAIA('something')
string_value = c_wchar_p()
result = dll2.GIDItem(pa,'CM',byref(string_value))
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot Mark! It worked well and fine.. It's getting the expected result. But I have the only thing if you how to enable the logs so that that I can log any error when we have any error when we called function from ctypes.